# Unexecpected white, square dialogue appearing in the middle of the screen: Map Data ... Google maps

Tags: openlayers-2, google

I have this code and some of the time, I have a dialogue that is

displayed in the middle of the map:

Google Maps

Map data (c)2012 Google

```
   var map;
   var vectors;
   var epsg900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');
   var epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');


   function initialize() {
       var control, renderer=OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
       renderer= (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;
       // Create the map object
       map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        //Create a Google layer
       var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
           "Google Streets", // the default
             {numZoomLevels: 20}
       );
       var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'});
       
       
       vectors= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
          "Vector Layer",
           {
               renderers:renderer
           }
       );

       map.addLayers([gmap,vectors]);
       
       map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
       map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
       
       control=new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors,OpenLayers.Handler.Path);
       map.addControl(control);
       control.activate();
       // Zoom to Vancouver, BC
       map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-123.12, 49.28).transform(epsg4326, epsg900913), 13);         
  }
```

Does anyone know where is this coming from?

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20604/google-maps-layer-copyright-popup-every-time-map-updated-user-input and my answer there.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same behaviour as reported here: [How to close watermarks window in QGIS Openlayers plugin?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24646/how-to-close-watermarks-window-in-qgis-openlayers-plugin)

It's reported here: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/2984

and solved here: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/commit/92f04a7a4277a6c818ef2d40a2856910ed72d3d6

So, either try the nightly build of openLayers, wait for next release, or apply the patch yourself.